# How to use variables in selector in Playwright C#?

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-sharp, playwright-dotnet

So we are validating the text present in our site using the excel sheet.

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
{
    string ServiceName = ExcelFunction.getCellValue(filepath, TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.MethodName, "ServiceName", i);
    ILocator service17 = page.Locator("//span[text()=ServiceName]");// here I want to append the ServiceName that I get from excel sheet to the selector.
}
```

Is there any way to append the variables in selectors in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ILocator service17 = page.Locator("//span[text()=ServiceName" + ServiceName + "]");
```